# error starting .bna file on local hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have been roughly referring to this, for deploying my business network on playgroung locally.

```
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/bnd-deploy
```

I am able to install the `.bna` file using the command,

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile test-bank@0.0.1.bna
```

but am unable to start it. the following command throws an error, says that "`archiveFile`" is an undefined argument.

```
 composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --archiveFile test-bank@0.0.1.bna --file networkadmin.card --networkName test-bank --networkVersion 1.0.0
```

[screencap of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZj8A.png)

Comment: try removing `--archiveFile test-bank@0.0.1.bna` from the start command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the old command format. New command format is different which doesn't have archiveFile argument. Refer this link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.network.start.
Required fields in the new command format are network name ,version, admin identity, secret and PeerAdmin card that you have imported.

Answer (score 0):

The archiveFile argument is deprecated in latest versions. What version of composer are you using? In composer 0.19.5 the following commands work fine

```
composer network install -a your-network.bna -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1

composer network start --networkName your-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw
```